# Working with file from google cloud storage

Tags: java, file, google-cloud-storage

I'm refactoring my code to work with GCS and not just locally, I am parsing xml files.

My original code:

```
File file = new File("localpath.xml");
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.instance().newDocumentBuilder();
Document d = docBuilder.parse(file);
```

However, now due to gcs it looks like this:

```
Blob blob = storage.get(bucketName, filePath);
ReadChannel readChannel = blob.reader();
```

Now that I have the content in my readChannel, how do I convert that to a File object? Is there a way to work with this without restructuring all of my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than convert to a Java File object, we should understand that a ReadChannel object has a read method (see https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-clients/0.97.0-alpha/com/google/cloud/ReadChannel.html).  Through the read() method you can populate a ByteBuffer object.  At this point you now have the content of the GCS blob in your Java app as a ByteBuffer object.

Given a ByteBuffer, you can now get access to the data as a byte[] array using the array() method (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#array()).  Now that you have a byte[] array, you can wrap that in an Input Stream (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html).

And finally ... we have gone from a ReadChannel -> InputStream and you can parse the content using the DocumentBuilder parse() method which has an overload that takes an InputStream ...

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html#parse(java.io.InputStream)

... later ...

Perhaps a simpler story is to realize that given a Blob object, we can go straight to the byte[] array using [Blob.getContent()](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-clients/latest/com/google/cloud/storage/Blob.html#getContent-com.google.cloud.storage.Blob.BlobSourceOption...-).  Once we have the byte[] we can create the ByteArrayInputStream needed for the DocumentBuilder.parse().

Comment: Hmm, can I do that directly? I was doing some further research and found I might need to use a BufferedReader which takes the readChannel and encoding, but I'm not sure

Comment: I *think* you can do what I suggested ... but I haven't tried it myself ... however the bits seem to chain together (at least in theory).  Maybe give it a try and see where we fall down ...

Comment: I'm trying what you suggested, but on the first step when I'm using ReadChannel.read() it expects a ByteBuffer() as a destination parameter and I'm not sure how much to allocate

Comment: Ive update the answer with a new thought ... instead of going through ReadChannel, just ask the Blob for its byte[] and create the input stream from there.  No channel and no ByteBuffer.